# Can code violations be overturned?

Tags: rules, tennis

When Serena Williams was awarded her third code violation during the recently concluded US Open Finals against Naomi Osaka, US Open Referee Brian Earley and WTA Supervisor Donna Kelso were also called to the court due to the dispute between Serena and chair umpire Carlos Ramos over the code violations.

This was also the case during the 2009 US Open semifinals after Serena lashed out at a lineswoman who called a foot fault on her second serve that gave Kim Clijsters match point. The chair umpire, US Open referee, the lineswoman and Serena herself were seen disputing the incident that eventually lead to Serena defaulting on match point.

While I understand that these discussions with the tournament referee and organization officials are for clearing things with the players, as with the several infamous instances of this involving John McEnroe, can the tournament referees or WTA/ATP officials actually overturn any code violation awarded to a player as a result of these on-court discussions?